# Change to linq left join query

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

```
SELECT I.*, SI.SupplierID FROM item I
LEFT JOIN SupplierItem SI ON I.ItemID = SI.ItemID AND I.Price = SI.Price
WHERE I.CurrentQty <= I.ReorderLevel and SI.SupplierID = 'AlPA'
```

how can i change that sql query to Linq Query.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and [mcve] for asking better received questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below query will convert your Sql query to Linq query

```
var data = 
    from row in db.item
    join row1 in db.SupplierItem
        on new { ID= row.ItemID , Price = row.Price } 
        equals new { ID= row1.ItemID , Price = row1.Price } into joinedData
    from row2 in joinedData.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where row.CurrentQty <= row.ReorderLevel && row2.SupplierID == "AlPA"
    select new {
        item = row,
        SupplierID = row2.SupplierID
    };
```

Comment: are you getting any compile time error or run time?

Comment: can you send me your sample data for both tables
it will be easy to check at my end

Comment: ItemID SupplierID Price
C001 ALPA 0.4
C002 ALPA 0.5
C003 ALPA 0.9
C004 ALPA 1
C005 ALPA 0.8  
ItemID Description ReorderLevel ReorderQty UnitOfMeasure CurrentQty CategoryName Price Bin
C001 Clips Double 1'' 50 35 Dozen 40 Clip 0.4 A1
C002 Clips Double 2'' 50 30 Dozen 44 Clip 0.39 A2
C003 Clips Double 3/4'' 50 30 Dozen 145 Clip 0.9 A3
C004 Clpis Paper Large 50 30 Box 78 Clip 1 A4
C005 Clpis Paper Medium 50 30 Box 65 Clip 0.8 A5

that is 2 tables item and supplieritem

Comment: my query is working against your sample data
i added the below code to check output

string final = "";
            foreach (var d in data)
            {
                final = final + "\n" + d.item.ItemID + " " + d.item.Price + " " + d.SupplierID;
            }

and when you will print final you will get below output
C001 0.4 C001
C002 0.5 
C003 0.9 C003
C004 1.0 C004
C005 0.8 C005

Comment: Thanks, my mistake, i pass wrong id, the query was working :D